# Vite/Typescript/React: Build a js file for each source tsx file instead of bundling into one

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, vite, esbuild

I'm using a vite, rtk, typescript template for building a component lib package for my tool stack. This template provides a "tsc && vite build" script that runs ts validations (tsc with noEmit option) and vite build in turn uses esbuild to generate built up package.

Here's what I need:

- For each source tsx file generate a .js, dts .d.ts and a map file .js.map and also retain the "src" folder structure (I'm sure this generation pattern is called something that I couldn't find)
- Use vite and hence esbuild to achieve performance benefits that esbuild promises
- Not use webpack

What happens:

Script - **tsc && vite build**: Generates a build directory with "assets" directory that contains a single file each for js, css and an html file.
Script - **npx tsc** with compile options declarations: true and noEmit removed: While it generates desired structure with each of compiled js, dts and map files but doesn't know how to parse scss

Anyway to accomplish this structure using vite/esbuild?